# Permissions required for an account to use a Windows Service

Tags: windows, permissions, login, services, windows-services

I want to know if there are any specific permissions required on an account to use a Windows Service.

Note that I am not talking about starting and stopping a service, I am talking about the account specified under the Log On tab of the Service properties:
[image]

I thought these would have to be admin users, but I have had some that work without being admin.

Background to this is we have a service that uses an exe via COM. The Service worked fine on its own, but when running the exe it failed - until we made the account a member of local admin.

It did also work fine with the exe under the local system account but presumably that has admin rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account needs the ["Log on as a service"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424(v=ws.10).aspx) right, which services.msc grants automatically. You can do that via secpol.msc or Group Policy, under "User Rights Assignment".